# FME explode cells

Tags: fme-form, dgn, microstation

I want to ask if anyone knows how to explode a DGNV8 cell in FME workbench so that it is exported out as a single point to a mdb.I have read a little documentation and it seems I need to set the explode cells parameter to yes, the only problem is that I can't find this setting anywhere. I have tried to find the explode cell setting in fme workbench parameters, but have only come across "Expand named cells" and "Preserve Named Cell insert point" which does not give me the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Setting Expand Named Cells to Yes (and Preserve Named Cell Insert Point to No) should give you the results you need.

If not, then try adding a Visualizer/Inspector transformer mid-workspace to check that the cells are being exploded as expected. If they are, then any remaining problem must be in writing the data (maybe the output feature type (table) is set to allow point geometry only?)